# XStream xsd validation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xstream

I don't know if java XStream API provide xsd validation while marshal and unmarshal java objects.

If it does, can any one please provide me an example how XStream API  do xsd validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't do that with XStream. If you want/need a schema, perhaps you can check out [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/). Here's [an article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html) on JAXB/XSD validation.

Comment: Is this still the case that XStream does not allow creation of a schema?